# image_tag in rails view takes a long time to render in controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, haml, ruby-on-rails-6, minitest

I have a test that visits an index view and makes a simple assertion (here is a simplified version):

```
setup { login(@user) }

should 'have expected content' do
    get :index

    assert_match 'some content', response.body
end
```

The test takes > 100 seconds to complete, and after some debugging, I found that the culprit is an [`image_tag`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)

```
= image_tag 'file-csv-solid.svg', alt: 'CSV Download'
```

The image itself is stored in `assets/images/file-csv-solid.svg`. When viewing the app, the image renders as expected in a reasonable amount of time. Even in the test, the image renders with the correct path:

```
<img alt="CSV Download" src="/assets/file-csv-solid-cf0f63e5f766b9eddbc3d4f926a0f4d3c085bd52855958215c9dc659d308075a.svg">
```

The only problem is, it just takes too long to render. In my logs I see this:

```
Rendered path/to/index.haml (Duration: 106283.1ms | Allocations: 71099973)
```

When I comment out the `image_tag`, the same test only takes a few ms to complete.

My question is: why is it taking so long for the image tag to render, and how can I speed it up (or just skip it's rendering - I don't actual care about the image in my test)?

I am using Rails `6.0.3.4`. I assume I just need to adjust some `config.assets.*` setting in my test config, but I have tried a few different settings without success.

Comment: Did you try to use a different format of image? i.e. 'file-csv-solid.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the issue. I *think* that rails/sprockets was trying to precompile and cache assets in the test, but the precompile command was raising an error because of an unrelated issue.

Thanks to the comment by @eux above, I tried swapping out my svg for an existing jpg, and the test was fast. Then I tried swapping it for a different existing svg and it was *still* fast. So I went looking for the difference between the svg I was trying to use, and the existing one. The difference was that one existed in `tmp/cache/assets/sprockets/` and `public/assets/.sprockets-manifest`, while the new one I was trying to add did not. I ran `rails assets:precompile` to try to get my svg cached there too, and saw an unrelated error preventing the precompile process from completing. Once I resolved that issue, the svg was cached, and the test succeeded at normal speed.

## tldr:

If you are experiencing this issues, try running `rails assets:precompile` to see if there are some issues there. If that command fails (because of, e.g., some issues with some local `node_modules` as was my case), that could be a) preventing your assets from being cached, and b) slow down your tests because the failing precompile command takes much longer to complete than the succeeding one.